# Отправка post запроса API python

Tags: python-3.x, api, requests, https

Всем привет, помогите отправить POST запрос через requests отправлял как data, json, params ответ один и тот же {"error": true}, sID и другая информация получена верно, парсится после каждого перемещения.

[image: Это вид запроса на сайте]

Comment: Я сравнивал с другими запросами, там все построчно и с ними при post отправке проблем нет... а тут data: {} - не понимаю как отправлять такие данные... обычной строкой... ругается на первый ключ "method"

Comment: пробовал отправлять {"data": {"method":"*********","args":{},"batch":[],"uniqueSid":"************"}} при отправке json - Server Error 500 при остальных так же {"error": true}

Answer (score 0):

Порой без исходников никуда, пришлось лесть в них и увидеть url:"/api/",data:{data:JSON.stringify(c)} сделал такое же с json.dumps и добавил "data" : {} сообщение ответа изменилось